# how to find a value in array of objects mongoose

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

i have a collection name's groups and i want to get all groups that have a given id in field members, thanks for help
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but if you want to find all the documents that contain a given members `_id`, you would do: `db.collection.find( { "members._id": memberId } )`

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have a collection name's groups, and i need to get all groups thats have a given memberId

Comment: In that case my answer should stand; you would query with `Groups.find({ "members._id": memberId })`, using dot notation to access an embedded document's key